# MVC4 / Mocking Controller.Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I´m currently working on a MVC4 Project. As I did a few refactorings the tests should be changed too.

In the first scenario a session hash had to be passed included within the URL. That being nasted, I decided to pass it to the server as a Request header.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate(ClipGenerateRequest request)
{
    string hash = Request.Headers["hash"];

    ClipGenerationResponse responseModel = new ClipGenerationResponse();            

    return Json(responseModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem now seems to be that I'm unable to mock the Request object to a custom one as the Request object is a read-only object. Dynamically setting the header doesn't work, as the Request is null when performing Unit Tests. So the following won't work:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GenerateTest()
{
    GenerationController target = new GenerationController(this.loginModelMock, this.clipTemplateModelMock, this.clipTemplateFieldModelMock);
    target.Request = this.requestBase;
    string templateId = "0";

    ActionResult actual = target.Generate(templateId);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(JsonResult), actual.GetType());
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ClipGenerationResponse), ((JsonResult)actual).Data.GetType());
}
```

Where this.requestBase would be mock created with Moq.

```
public HttpContextBase CreateMockHttpContext()
{
    var serverVariables = new NameValueCollection {
        { "UserHostAddress", "127.0.0.1" },
        { "UserAgent", "Unit Test Value" }
    };

    var httpRequest = new Moq.Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    httpRequest.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(
        new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {
            {"hash", "somehash"}
        }
    );

    httpRequest.Setup(x => x.ServerVariables.Get(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns<string>(x =>
            {
                return serverVariables[x];
            });

    var httpContext = (new Moq.Mock<HttpContextBase>());
    httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(httpRequest.Object);

    return httpContext.Object;
}
```

Nor the static way would work:

```
target.Request.Headers["hash"] = "hash";
```

So, I'm wondering how this could be fixed **nicely**. I could always obtain the Request in the Constructor, set a class variable to hold the Request, and then mock the getter / setter for testing purposes, but I'd rather use a nicer way to do it. Though I don't seem to know a way to get it working.

PS: Please note that some class names may have been altered for preview.

### Update

As you seem to be unable to mock HttpContext.Current.Request, I decided to mock the HttpContext.Current. Resulting in:

```
container.RegisterInstance<HttpRequest>(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

Sadly this works for the API, but not for unit testing as HttpContext cannot e mocked as it's not an interface.

> Initialization method
>   SomeApiTest.Controllers.LoginControllerTest.Initialize
>   threw exception. System.NotSupportedException:
>   System.NotSupportedException: Type to mock must be an interface or an
>   abstract or non-sealed class. .

The suggested way was by doing:

```
container.RegisterInstance<HttpRequestBase>(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

But this doesn't work because Request cannot be cast to HttpRequestBase.

Which means, I do now have a way to unit test my code, but it will no longer be able to run..

---

Testing if this problem could be solved using a HttpRequestWrapper.

---

Looks like the following does work for testing:

```
HttpRequestBase requestBase = new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request);
container.RegisterInstance<HttpRequestBase>(requestBase);
```

But not for runtime. Because:
- Additional headers are not sent, such as: UserHostAddress, Custom Headers

with Postman is set with every request a custom header, named "hash". Using this method, it looks like these headers are no longer set.

---

Looks like headers are set when the method is called, but not when the Controller itself is created. Therefore Dependency Injection on this might not be suitable.

---

Ugly Temporary fix:

```
    private AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = null;
    private ILoginModel iLoginModel = null;
    private IModuleModel iModuleModel = null;
    private HttpRequestBase iRequestBase = null;

    public LoginController(ILoginModel loginModel, IModuleModel moduleModel, HttpRequestBase requestBase)
    {
        this.authenticationHelper = new AuthenticationHelper(loginModel);
        this.iLoginModel = loginModel;
        this.iModuleModel = moduleModel;
        this.iRequestBase = requestBase;
    }

    private HttpRequestBase GetRequestBase()
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            return Request;
        }
        else
        {
            return iRequestBase;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginRequest login)
    {
        var ip = this.authenticationHelper.GetIpAddress(GetRequestBase());
        var userAgent = this.authenticationHelper.GetUserAgent(GetRequestBase());
    }
```

Comment: in mock you can setup values to read only properties as well.... 

mockobject.SetupGet(i => i.ReadOnlyProperty).Returns("Return value");

May be you can try using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When within Controller you refer to something by static classes or Controller properties you usually shoot yourself in the boot, because you make your class not testable with unit test, as in your case. To avoid such situation is that your Controller gets HttpRequestBase injected with IoC. For instance with Autofac after you register module AutofacWebTypesModule your Controllers may accept in their constructor parameter of type HttpRequestBase with basically what you get with Register property. So you should make your controller look like this:

```
public class GenerationController : Controller
{
    readonly HttpRequestBase _request;
    public GenerationController(
            HttpRequestBase request,
            // Additional constructor parameters goes here
        )
    {
        _request = request;
    }
}
```

With Unity you should register factory for HttpRequestBase like this:

```
container
    .RegisterType<HttpRequestBase>(
        new InjectionFactory(c => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request))
    );
```

When you create your Controller within unit test it is extremely easy to mock HttpRequestBase as all its properties, along with Headers are virtual.

This is approach I usually use in my projects. However there is option to mock Controller Request property even without rewriting your original code. It involves use of Controller ControllerContext property:

```
Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
Mock<HttpRequestBase> httpReguestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
httpContextMock.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(httpReguestMock.Object);
GenerationController controller = new GenerationController();

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
controller.Index();
```

Comment: I'm using Unity for dependency injection, but your suggestion is adding the request to the constructor?

Comment: As far as I know Unity as Autofac by default provides dependencies in form of constructor parameters, so yes, this is what you should do. With unity make registration container.RegisterInstance<HttpRequestBase>(HttpContext.Current.Request); and now it can be resolver when your controller is being created. In unit test just pass to controller constructor Mock deriving from HttpRequestBase.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't work at all with Unity so I made a mistake. What you need is to register Factory with Unity. I editted my answer to include this. I checked it and it works.

Comment: Awesome it works, though I did pass the requestmock with the creation of the controller :]

Answer (score 0):

My mock for request looks:

```
var request = A.Fake<HttpRequestBase>();
var formCollection = new NameValueCollection();
A.CallTo(() => request.HttpMethod).Returns("POST");
A.CallTo(() => request.Headers).Returns(new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
{
        {"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"}
});
A.CallTo(() => request.Form).Returns(formCollection);
A.CallTo(() => request.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
```

For my needs it works. I'am using FakeItEasy to mock request, but I'm pretty sure that you can use Moq instead. I'm using FakeItEasy and Moq parallel in my project, and it works perfect.